# How do I prevent thumbstrip from jumping back to top upon closing expanded image?

Tags: highslide

I've searched the (now closed) forums, and searched all the questions here tagged with Highslide, and haven't discovered what I believe is a simple fix.

Highslide works perfectly, no issues, this is more of an interface thing. If I load a page that has enough thumbnail images, naturally, a scroll bar gets generated. If, using that thumbstrip (which is vertical, if it matters) you scroll to a thumbnail that was "off-screen" and click, the expanded image pops up like it should.

However, at the same time, the thumbstrip scrolls right back to the top, so when the expanded image gets closed, you have to scroll the thumbstrip back down to where you were.

What I'd like to happen is for the thumbstrip not to scroll when a thumbnail gets clicked. (Obviously, if there aren't too many thumbnails, then no scroll bar gets generated and there is no thumbstrip jump.)

To see a live page of what I am referring, go to http://www.crown-point.com/gallery/index.html, click on 91, and then use the thumbstrip to scroll to an off-screen thumbnail. When you click that thumbnail, you will see the expanded image, but also the thumbstrip jumping back to the top.

I hope I've explained myself well, and thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you’re seeing is normal behavior for a thumbstrip with `mode: 'float'` (thumbstrip with scrollbar).

If you want different behavior for the thumbstrip, you should try a thumbstrip with `mode: 'vertical'` (thumbstrip with scrollarrows instead of scrollbar).

See this demo gallery: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-thumbstrip-leftpanel.html 
(this demo gallery has the thumbstrip in `position: 'leftpanel'` - change it to `position: 'rightpanel'` to make it look similar to your gallery)

Comment: Yes, Ms RR, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much! :) And I also really like that triangle indicator that points to the current thumbnail! I looked in the Highslide API Reference for adding that ability, but didn't see it. Am I overlooking it? Thanks again!

Comment: The triangle indicator is a built-in function for the galleries that have the thumbstrip in `mode: 'vertical'` or `mode: 'horizontal'`. Three examples: [vertical thumbstrip](http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-vertical-strip.html) - [horizontal thumbstrip](http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-horizontal-strip.html) - [thumbstrip above](http://highslide.com/examples/gallery-thumbstrip-above.html)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in thanking you! I believe that the triangle must be there, I'm sure it just isn't visible with my background set to white! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: The triangle will be set to white if you’re using `wrapperClassName: 'dark'`. I looked at your page now (http://www.crown-point.com/gallery/index.html) and I saw that you’re still using `mode: 'float'`. There’s no triangle available for this type of thumbstrip gallery. If you have another gallery with `mode: 'vertical'` to show me, I can show you where in the CSS you can change the color for the triangle.

Comment: You are so patient, I really appreciate your time! :) I've only recently been able to get back to this, and am going to spend some time digging into `mode:'vertical'` as I like the triangle indicator. I made the change in my code, and now I can see the triangle. I just need to adjust something else, because I can arrow through the thumbnails and see every large image available, but the thumbnails appear fixed; i.e., any thumbnail not visible upon page load stays "off-screen". Clicking the "up" triangle doesn't cause any action. I'm sure it's a simple setting. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've finally found what’s causing the error: You’ve changed this line in your highslide-with-gallery.js file: `floatMode = (mode == 'float'),` to this: `floatMode = (mode == 'vertical'),` You should never change anything below the line that says `// END OF YOUR SETTINGS` in the js file.

Comment: RR, you are gifted! Thank you so much! You were absolutely correct. I'm embarrassed at my stupidity. I hereby nominate you for the "Internet Perseverance Award!" Well...there ought to be an award for that. You are a gem.